# preg_match if string contain + or -

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How to validate if a string contain either `+` or `-` ??

```
preg_match('[\-\+]', '(292+3)*1', $match);
print_r($match);

preg_match('[\-\+]', '(292-3)*1', $match);
print_r($match);
```

## output

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

Comment: no need of escaping `-` or `+` in character class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex must be between delimiters:

```
preg_match('/[-+]/', '(292+3)*1', $match);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this without regex.

Use [strpos() function.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$str = '+123-';

if (strpos($str, '+') !== FALSE || strpos($str, '-') !== FALSE) {
     echo 'Found it';
} else {
     echo 'Not found.';
}
```

Hope this helps.